# How to minimize average waiting duration for two queues?

Tags: c#, queue, priority-queue

First of all, this is a homework, if you haven't already guessed it.

There are two imaginary printers, with one working as a FIFO queue and printing 6 pages per second, and the other one working as a PQ and printing 10 pages per second. There's a set of printing jobs, namely `{21, 27, 41, 15, 3, 35, 43, 12, 17}`, which must be distributed to printers in a way that the total average waiting time for both queues must be minimized to lowest possible. For example; if one sends `{21, 27}` to FIFO printer, the waiting durations will be 3.5 and 8 seconds (3.5 from the first job + 4.5 from the second job) respectively, and the average waiting duration will be 5.75 seconds. If the same set of jobs were to sent to the PQ printer, the waiting durations would've been 2.1 and 4.8 seconds respectively, and the average waiting duration would've been 3.45 seconds.

It is not possible to change jobs places in a set (e.g. you can't send 27 before 21 to the FIFO printer), but all the jobs are being sent at almost the same time so the PQ printer can sort them in ascending order.

I couldn't write any code for this because I didn't manage to find a sensible way to distribute the jobs. I've tried to route them in a way that PQ printer were assigned the smallest jobs totaling at the half of the total page count (or the closest count possible); and FIFO printer were assigned the rest of the jobs. With this approach, I got 6.63 seconds but I was wondering if there could be a more systematic method for this, as what I've done was just splitting the chunk in half.

Thanks for any input on this.

Comment: There is no maximum waiting time? How do we know how many pages a job contains? Seems like you want to distribute jobs so that the PQ printer gets approximately 10 pages for every 6 pages that the FIFO printer gets. But if there's a restriction on the order in which jobs can be sent to the queue, that becomes a little tricky. As written, I don't think your question has all the information we need to help you solve the problem.

Comment: @JimMischel Believe me, it's all I have too. Let me elaborate a little bit. There is no maximum waiting time, the integers in the brackets are the page counts of jobs, e. g. first job has 21 pages, second 27, etc. Restriction is this way; you can select individual jobs to be sent to different printers. The ones routed to PQ printer will be sorted in ascending order. But the ones routed to the FIFO, they will just be placed in the same order of the set. For an example, if one routes 21 and 3 to PQ, and 41 and 27 to FIFO, PQ's order will be {3, 21} and FIFO's order will be {27, 41}.

Comment: Why would FIFO order be {27,41} if you sent them in the order {41,27}?

Comment: @JimMischel Because the original order of the set matters when sending to FIFO queue.

Comment: My point exactly. If you add 41 to the queue, and then 27, then 41 will be the first item processed. Your example says that 27 would be the first item processed.

Comment: @JimMischel It seems like I can't properly explain myself. 27 has to be the first item to sent because rules state it so. You do not have the option to send 41 before 27, because it's not correspondent with job set.